# Prometheus - many-to-many matching not allowed

Tags: prometheus

I’m trying to use for the first time vector matching and I’m getting an error saying “many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels must be unique on one side” and I don’t understand why.

Here is my expression :

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{image!="",pod_name=~"sentry.*",container_name!="POD"}[5m])) by (container_name) 
* on (container_name) group_left(container) 
avg by (container) (kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores{container=~"sentry.*"})
```

The result for both vector is

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{image!=“”,pod_name=~“sentry.*“,container_name!=“POD”}[5m])) by (pod_name, namespace,container_name)


{container_name="sentry-web",namespace="infrastructure",pod_name="sentry-web-65757bf8f6-cgmsw"}
{container_name="sentry-statsds",namespace="infrastructure",pod_name="sentry-statsd-849699fb56-jnljm"}
{container_name="sentry-k8s",namespace="infrastructure",pod_name="sentry-k8s-66b9b88758-stn5x"}
{container_name="sentry-cron",namespace="infrastructure",pod_name="sentry-cron-7dcdfc5688-qh55k"}
{container_name="redis-exporter",namespace="infrastructure",pod_name="sentry-redis-exporter-779f4f85cb-clmc7"}
{container_name="rds-exporter",namespace="infrastructure",pod_name="sentry-rds-exporter-54bb4dcd8d-h5rh5"}
{container_name="nginx-exporter",namespace="infrastructure",pod_name="sentry-web-75959bc475-4dpg2"}
{container_name="nginx-exporter",namespace="infrastructure",pod_name="sentry-web-65757bf8f6-cgmsw"}
{container_name="nginx",namespace="infrastructure",pod_name="sentry-web-75959bc475-4dpg2"}
```

`avg by (container) (kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores{container=~“sentry.*“})`

```
{container="sentry-k8s"}    0.1
{container="sentry-statsds"}    0.1
{container="sentry-cron"}    0.1
{container="sentry-workers"}    0.5
{container="sentry-web"}    1
```

The second vector have uniq labels so why I’m getting this error ? Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RHS  all have the same `container_name` label, as they have no `container_name` label so this ends up as a many to many match. What you probably want to do here is use `label_replace` to rename the label, or fix the source of the labels to have consistent naming.